# What does 'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple' mean in my code

Tags: python

So I got this message in my code and am not sure how to fix it. I have tried looking at other peoples questions however they don't seem to relate to mine.

The Problem is located on the 6th line of the third block of code.

```
coc =float(Cappacuino.get())
col= float(Latte.get())
cofw= float(Flat_White.get())
cob= float(Black_Coffee.get())
coa= float(Americano.get())
cof= float(Frappe.get())

costofcappacuino = coc*4
costoflatte = col*4
costofflatwhite = cofw*3
costofblackcoffee = cob*3
costofamericano = coa*4
costoffrappe = cof*5

costoforder = "$",str('%.2f'% (costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee + costofamericano + costoffrappe))
PayTax=((costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee +  costofamericano + costoffrappe)*0.15)
Totalcost=(costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee  + costofamericano + costoffrappe)
Disscount=((costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee + costofamericano + costoffrappe)/10)
Disscount="$",str('%.2f'% Disscount)
OverAllCost="$",str( PayTax + Totalcost - Disscount)
PaidTax="$",str('%.2f'% PayTax)

Disscount.set(Disscount)
cost.set(costoforder)
Tax.set(PaidTax)
Subtotal.set(costoforder)
Total.set(OverAllCost)


Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/samjones/Documents/source/CoffeeShop.py", line 49, in Ref
OverAllCost="$"+str( PayTax + Totalcost - Disscount)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Please post a text copy of the full error and backtrace

Comment: When you do `Disscount="$",str('%.2f'% Disscount)` the comma means that `Disscount` is now a *tuple*.  Didi you mean `+` to concatenate the strings?

Comment: xception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/samjones/Documents/source/CoffeeShop.py", line 49, in Ref
    OverAllCost="$",str( PayTax + Totalcost - Disscount)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'

Comment: Please paste the error in you question, not in a comment.  However, my previous comment answers your issue I think, you are using `,` instead of `+`.

Comment: I just added a + instead of the comma but it still came up with the same error.

Comment: Maybe you save the `Frappe` in the form of "$xx.yy". Even do not use `float` for this. Use `decimal` instead.

Comment: You define `costoforder` as a tuple, with two items: `"$"` and the rest of the string. Note that the comma makes the tuple, even without parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  First you are using `,` instead of `+` - the comma creates a tuple.  Second you make `Disscount` a string then try to use it as a float.  Just swap two statements around:

```
costoforder = "$"+str('%.2f'% (costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee + costofamericano + costoffrappe))
PayTax=((costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee +  costofamericano + costoffrappe)*0.15)
Totalcost=(costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee  + costofamericano + costoffrappe)
Disscount=((costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee + costofamericano + costoffrappe)/10)

OverAllCost="$"+str( PayTax + Totalcost - Disscount)    # <<<< moved
Disscount="$"+str('%.2f'% Disscount)                    # <<<< moved

PaidTax="$"+str('%.2f'% PayTax)
```

You can avoid some of these complications with a simpler line like this (for example):

```
PaidTax = "$%.2f" % PayTax
```

One other thing, using `%.2f` rounding and `float` for money amounts is very bad practice and would land you in deep trouble with accountants.  The rounding type and the rounding errors are not acceptable for money in the real world.  Unfortunately there are many tutorials (and tutors) out there which do this!

Comment: hey thanks a lot, the discount with 2 s is just because I use discount already as a variable and haven't changed yet

Comment: Sorry, it was a stupid remark of mine - no one expects programmers to spell :-)  See my suggestion for simpler string construction.

Comment: Yeah. I'm very new to python and need to do it for class but my teacher tells us nothing. One thing. It says: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set' do you mind telling me what this means thank you.

Comment: @SJONES:  literally it means you are trying to use (probably call) an attribute called `set` which does not exist in the `str` class.  It usually means that you have the wrong type.  I would have to see the context of what you are trying to do to give you the correct code.  Maybe you should post a new question?

Comment: Yeah ill do that. I will post the whole code in the new question.

Comment: I can't post another question as I posted one recently

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "Disscount" converts to a tuple after the 5th line of the third block. So in line 6, you will get that error. Just change the name of that variable and it probably will be ok.

Comment: I tried changing it as it was discount before so I just added an s to try it. Ill try again though.